# I bake normal maps and get a gray thing

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-baking, baking, normal-map

Why when I try to bake a normal map in blender 3.3.1 I get a gray weird thing. Whatever I do, instead of a normal map, I get a gray thing. I tried to flip the normals, I tried to select the heads in different order, I tried to change the size of the head and I tried to change the settings in the bake section, changed the max ray distance and extrusion, nothing helps. I even tried to find a solution to a similar problem in Google, but it did not help either. The only thing that helped was to download the old version of blender 2.8 and the normal map is baked well in it. In the new version, nothing works for me, what could be the problem?
[Blender File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FLBihdY_CzxDQGF69Vm33C2vv1lOvfxM/view?usp=sharing)

[image: this is what i get when baking a normal map]

Comment: I find baking normal map from a multires modifier much easier, you could try it

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yes, I forgot to write about multires, with it my normal map is baked well. But I'm wondering why I can't bake the old way with two models. Maybe somewhere you can change one parameter and everything will work or something like that. It haunts me and I constantly think about it...

Comment: Not sure why it doesn't work for you. I've disconnected the *Image Texture* node, lowered the sample count to 10, and it baked fine in Blender 3.3.0

Comment: I downloaded version 3.3.0 in it doesn't work for me either, but I tried version 3.0.0 and baking still works in it. Is it possible that my computer is just outdated for baking normals in the new blender? I have a powerful GT 440 and an incredible AMD Phenom II x6 1035t. What do you think?

Comment: I don't know.  An old GPU should not matter if you bake with the CPU. I have a "powerful" onboard graphic chip and only can use the CPU for Cycles.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is several months old but I realized my normals were flipped. If you're getting gray colors on your baked normal maps, check if your model has normals oriented the right way. Check the overlay "Face Orientation" and make sure outside faces are blue

[image: Option]

---

✅ Correct / ⛔ Wrong:

[image: Correct model]
[image: Wrong faces]

Comment: Second issue: Source object had a NORMAL MAP attached. Remove any normal maps from the source geometry